# Selenium, updating rows, refreshing, stale items

Tags: selenium-webdriver-c#

I have a table of charges, I am creating an array of elements of the rows.  I go through the line items and zero them out.

The issue is, each of these are handled by modal windows. It pops up, I zero it out, and I click on save. returns control back to the rows and it refreshes the total column with zeroes.

I try to grab the next row, but since it refreshes, the dom is stale. i want to refresh it, but I am hoping I don't have to cycle through the for loop again and pick up where I left off. Anyone create any kind of method for this? Or have some good ideas I have not been able to figure out yet?

Comment: You summed it up pretty well but can you share your relevant code part too?

Comment: It is ok. I basicallyhave an external forloop that goes thru the table in its original form, and keep a count of the row that it is on. I pass it into a function and reload the table into a webelement, and go through each one and see if I am on the 'next' row. The horrible thing about this is if I have a large table to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

1. Check the number of items in a line. Save it to some `int` value
2. Each time you're entering the step of clearing the cell out, locate your current element using the index (build a separate xpath and create new locator for each item)

You won't be storing the big part of DOM, only the one you're working with in each particular case so that nothing would go stale.

Comment: This is what I exactly ended up doing. Hated having to do it this way though. But marked this as the answer since I can't mark my own.

Comment: @GregP Thanks. However you can mark your own answers as correct :).

Comment: No. I can't, I don't have that many points yet..haha.